# Request failed. Unexpected response from server. null error in Sharepoint 2013 online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am working on a task where we have to get all the values from a list named 'Employees' based on logged in user and load in a custom form. 
From this form, when we click on 'Submit', all the details has to be set or stored in 'Nominations' form. 
All the functionality is fine and the values are stored in the list perfectly.
The only problem is alert, when the values are added, it is showing a failure error as:

> Request failed. Unexpected response from server. null

Please help how to overcome this error.

This is my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/AddNominees/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/AddNominees/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/dev/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>

<div class="nominee">
  <div class="form-style-4">
    <label for="field1">
      <div>Employee ID</div><input type="text" name="field1" id="emp_id" disabled  />
    </label>
    <label for="field2">
      <div>Employee Name</div><input type="text" name="field2" id="emp_name" disabled />
    </label>
    <label for="field3">
      <div>Grade</div><input type="text" name="field3" id="grade" disabled />
    </label>
    <label for="field1">
      <div>EMail ID</div><input type="text" name="field1" id="user_email" disabled  />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkExistingNominees();"/>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript file, main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {           
    retrieveListItems();  
    });    

});

var checks = '';
var checksCount = '';

function retrieveListItems() {
debugger;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EmployeeName\' LookupId="True" />' +
            '<Value Type="User">' +_spPageContextInfo.userId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem,'Include(EMPID, EmployeeName, EMail, Grade)');
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    debugger;
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();     


    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();       
        $("#emp_id").val(oListItem.get_item('EMPID'));
        $("#emp_name").val(oListItem.get_item('EmployeeName').get_lookupValue());
        $("#user_email").val(oListItem.get_item('EMail'));
    }

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}

function checkExistingNominees()
{
    debugger;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Nominations');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EmployeeName\'/>' +
            '<Value Type="Lookup">' + empName + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    checks = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(checks);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded3), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed3)); 
}
function onQuerySucceeded3(sender, args)
{
    checksCount = checks.get_count();
    if(checksCount > 0)
    {
        alert("You are already registered to this training");
        closeModalDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        createListItem();
    }
}

function onQueryFailed3(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}

function createListItem() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var listName = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Nominations');
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
    var txtEmpID = document.getElementById('emp_id').value; 
    var txtEmpName = document.getElementById('emp_name').value;
    var txtGrade = document.getElementById('grade').value;
    var txtEMailID = document.getElementById('user_email').value;       
   var oListItem = listName.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
   oListItem.set_item('EMPID', txtEmpID); 
   oListItem.set_item('EmployeeName', SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(txtEmpName) ); 
   oListItem.set_item('Grade', txtGrade); 
   oListItem.set_item('EMail', txtEMailID); 
   oListItem.update();
   clientContext.load(oListItem);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySuccess), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFail)
    );

}

function onQuerySuccess() {
     alert('Nomination added successfully ');
     closeModalDialog();

}

function onQueryFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you are not assigning a value to empName property.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef 
Name=\'EmployeeName\'/>'+
'<Value Type="Lookup">' + **empName** + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```